# Python: move a file up one directory

Tags: python-3.x, directory, shutil, pathlib

Below is a small test routine which takes a path to a file and moves the file up one directory. I am using the os and shutil modules, is there one module that could perform this task? Is there a more pythonic way of implementing this functionality?

The code below is running on windows, but the best cross-platform solution would be appreciated.

```
def up_one_directory(path):
    """Move file in path up one directory"""
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    try:
        shutil.move(path, os.path.join(os.path.split(head)[0], tail))
    except Exception as ex:
        # report
        pass
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the same as [@thierry-lathuille's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49512320/4298200), but without requiring `shutil`:

```
p = Path(path).absolute()
parent_dir = p.parents[1]
p.rename(parent_dir / p.name)
```

Comment: Thought there were issues using rename, but I was incorrect - this worked a treat.

Comment: And note that we need to make sure the new path directory exists. In the case of the parent directory, this is always true.

Comment: `Path.rename` does not always work, for example when moving files from one drive to another. So this is NOT "the same" as the linked answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since Python 3.4, you can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

    
def up_one_dir(path):
    try:
        # from Python 3.6
        parent_dir = Path(path).parents[1]
        # for Python 3.4/3.5, use str to convert the path to string
        # parent_dir = str(Path(path).parents[1])
        shutil.move(path, parent_dir)
    except IndexError:
        # no upper directory
        pass
```

Comment: I think the os.path.join() would still be needed. "os.path.join(Path(path).parents[1], Path(path).name)"

Comment: No, see the doc for [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move): If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory.

Comment: My mistake, it didn't work and seen parent_dir didn't include the file.

Comment: Getting the following error: "TypeError: _isdir: illegal type for path parameter"

Comment: How do you call it? What version of Python are you using? I have no problem with Python 3.6.

Comment: Python 3.5.2 and "up_one_directory("C:\\Users\\SButler\\Desktop\\AF\\AF.c")"

Comment: I just updated the answer. Some changes have been made in pathlib and the standard library for 3.6, you must probably convert the Path objects to str with 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to move up one directory:

```
file_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("..")
folder_path = os.getcwd()
shutil.copy(file_path, folder_path)
```

Comment: I mean to take a physical file and move it from its current directory to the one the next level up.